# Error: "ArrayList has private access in Arrays" when trying to declare an ArrayList in a class

Tags: java, arraylist

Can't figure out what's going on here. I'm trying to make an ArrayList of "chore" objects. Here's the line of code that is having issues:

```
static ArrayList<chore> list = new ArrayList<chore>();
```

And yes, I have tried taking static off of it and it still doesn't make any difference, as that is the only thing I could think of that could possibly solve the problem. The error is making me think that I'm trying to access a private method but all I'm trying to do is initialize an ArrayList. Am I even using the correct syntax?

Comment: You need to import `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks! You now know that I am a beginner

Comment: Also, please follow Java naming conventions, or you'll end up in a lot of trouble. Class names start with a Capital, fields and local variables start with lowerCase, and both class names and fields and local variables follow CamelCase/camelCase. So the class should be named `Chore` and not `chore` - you can see in your question that the StackOverflow syntax coloring doesn't recognize `chore` as a class name.